# how to select one primary contact on listing of contacts in ng-repeat by radio button

Tags: angularjs

I have list of contacts and repeating with ng-repeat how to make one primary contact by selecting radio button .

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat='contact in acc.contacts'>

    <div class="col-xs-2" ng-class="{'error':(sub && !contact.isPrimary)}">
        <input type="radio" name='isPrimary' ng-model='contact.isPrimary' ng-value="true">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2" ng-class="{'error':(sub && !contact.name)}">
        <input type="text"  ng-model='contact.name'>
    </div>

</div>                
</div>
```

my json is look like

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "isPrimary": false,
            "name": null,
        },
        {
             "isPrimary": false,
             "name": null
        },
        {
             "isPrimary": false,
             "name": null
        ]
   }
```

i want isPrimary should be true for one , but it does not set false when radio button got deselected

Comment: you can use `ng-model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the radio button in an `ng-repeat` and the `ng-model` is a property of the repeated item, you can do it like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" ng-class="{'error':(sub && !contact.isPrimary)}">
    <input type="radio" name='isPrimary'
           ng-value="true"
           ng-change="primaryClicked(contact)">
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.primaryClicked = function(contact) {
    // Set all others on false
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.acc.contacts.length; i++) {
        $scope.acc.contacts[i].isPrimary = false;
    }

    // Set current on true
    contact.isPrimary = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to use ng-value.

Modify your code:

```
<label data-ng-repeat="contact in acc.contacts">
  <input type="radio"  data-ng-model="contact.isPrimary" data-ng-value="true" />
  {{contact.name}}
</label>
```

Hope this is helps you